# DropDownList in GridView Must Validate on Submit Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a `GridView` with `DropDownList` inside. I want `GridView` to be selected with all `DropDownList` value as "Yes". Currently I am having two listitems for dropdowns as "Yes" and "No". I have a `submit` button at the bottom of page. I have a condition where all the values in  the `GridView` should be as "Yes". None of them should be tagged as "No". When they click on `submit` button, it should only allow to move next page when all dropdown values are yes. else if any one of the row in `GridView` is set to "No". The page should restrict the user by showing error message.

Comment: What technology do you use? ASP.NET WebForms, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight?

Comment: use RequiredFieldValidator for validation.

Comment: Can you please send me any code example

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=RequiredFieldValidator

Comment: i have posted code check it.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlList" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" InitialValue="1" ControlToValidate="ddlList"
                    Enabled="false" Display="Static" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup ="gg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_Click"  CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup ="gg"/>
```